# When I create a copy of my excel file it creates a link to the original. How do I stop this?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am currently running a script that creates an excel backup of my current sheet, and emails it to another person.

Everytime I do this though, it create a link back to my original document. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I do not want the file I save or send to have a link back to the original, or even any links at all.

This my my code for saving the workbook

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Current.Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
wb.Activate
wb.SaveAs "E:\" & Current.Name & "-" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Are there references to cells in other sheets in the sheet you are copying?

Comment: There must be. possibly named ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the workbook being prepared for publication: on the Data tab of the Fluent Ribbon, select *Edit Links* from the *Connections* group and make an appropriate selection form the dialog box that appears.

[image]

You will have options to replace all links with the current value (which I believe to be most likely in your scenario), as well as to re-direct the links to another workbook.

Comment: In the Workbook being created there are no connection, just a link.
In the Workbook that I'm using to generate the files, it has connections, but on sheets not being utilized.

Comment: @JohnFayt: As I stated above: "Select *Edit Links* from the *Connections* tab ...." Note that **all links are connections** in EXCEL terminology.

Answer (score 0):

If you [RTFM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194915(v=office.14).aspx) you will see how to do this:

```
Sub breakLinks(wb As Workbook)
Dim ls As Variant, i As Long

  ls = wb.LinkSources(xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
  For i = 1 To UBound(ls)
    Debug.Print "breaking " & ls(i)
    wb.BreakLink ls(i), xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
  Next i

End Sub
```

Call signature:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Current.Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)

breaklinks wb

wb.Activate
wb.SaveAs "E:\" & Current.Name & "-" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Hey Cool Blue,
When I insert this code, it gives me the following error message
"Object doesn't support property or method"

Comment: @JohnFayt post your full code stating where each piec of code is located and show exactly where the error is and I'll have a look.