# Excel workbook reference severing

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a report template series, where I use a single source workbook to create multiple test reports. I basically copy data from different parts of the source workbook to the source workbooks calculation area and use the calculation area values as reference to create a report.

Problem is, that I want to create multiple reports back to back by changing the data in the calculation area. I have saved the reports as separate files, but the reference to the calculation area still exists and updates when the data is changed. Can I somehow break the source workbook references while keeping the values intact?

```
Option Explicit
Dim pinta1 As Range
Dim pinta2 As Range
Dim pinta3 As Range
Dim pinta4 As Range
Dim laskrivi1 As Range
Dim laskrivi2 As Range
Dim data As Workbook
Dim tipit As Worksheet

Sub My_sub()
Set pinta1 = Range("B12:B51")
Set pinta2 = Range("C12:C51")
Set laskrivi1 = Range("A101:A140")
Set laskrivi2 = Range("B101:B140")
Set data = Workbooks.Open("Source_workbook",,True)
Set tipit = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")

data.Activate
Range("pinta1").Copy Destination:=Range("laskrivi1")
Range("pinta2").Copy Destination:=Range("laskrivi2")

tipit.Activate
Range("C5").Formula = "=COUNT(Source_workbook!laskrivi2)"
Range("C7").Formula = "=COUNT(Source_workbook!laskrivi1)"
ActiveSheet.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Report file 1"

data.Activate
Range("pinta3").Copy Destination:=Range("laskrivi1")
Range("pinta4").Copy Destination:=Range("laskrivi2")

tipit.Activate
Range("C5").Formula = "=COUNT(Source_workbook!laskrivi2)"
Range("C7").Formula = "=COUNT(Source_workbook!laskrivi1)"
ActiveSheet.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Report file 2"
--> Here the data in Report file 1 gets replaced with data from Report file 2 due to source workbook reference
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [break link method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff194915(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Try the answer from [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137935/when-i-create-a-copy-of-my-excel-file-it-creates-a-link-to-the-original-how-do#:%7E:text=When%20I%20create%20a%20copy%20of%20my%20excel,file%20it%20creates%20a%20link%20to%20the%20original.):

```
tipit.Activate
Range("C5").Formula = "=COUNT(Source_workbook!laskrivi2)"
Range("C7").Formula = "=COUNT(Source_workbook!laskrivi1)"
ActiveSheet.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Report file 1"

Dim ls As Variant, i As Long
ls = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
For i = 1 To UBound(ls)
    Debug.Print "breaking " & ls(i)
    ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink ls(i), xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
Next i
```